# Magento 2.2.6 Installation

Tags: installation, magento2.2.6, file-permissions

I'm trying to install magento 2.2.6 on my local server but i'm facing permission issues.

How to set read write permissions to generated folder in windows7 with command line.

Thank you.

Comment: Window dont need to set permission. Can you please show your error?

Comment: you can set it from Properties and tick the `Read-only Attributes`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

> takeown /F

Example:

> takeown /F C:\wamp\www\Magento\www\pub\static